# obj c different table cell names in a table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to have table cells with different names, but so far they all have the text '1'.
How do I make the cells each have a unique name, as described in the tableData array?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;    
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
    tableData = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1", @"2", @"333", nil];  
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:   (NSInteger)section {
    return [tableData count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"subTable"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"CELL"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:0];
    return cell;
}
```

I heard that I might need to use a method 'forIndex' or 'indexPath' or some such?

Answer (score 2):

Change this line:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:0];
```

to this:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Not to be rude, just a thought: if this is not obvious to you, you should probably start with some beginner level tutorials.